# Hollywood actors whose voice is always substituted?

Tags: american-cinema, acting

Not sure if this is actually true but I have heard a few times that some actors' real voices are never used for one or another reason.

Are there actors in Hollywood whose voices are always substituted?

Comment: I've only heard of this for singing voices, not every line of dialogue.

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of the plot of *Singin' in the Rain*? That transition from silent to talkies is the only period I've ever heard of this occurring.

Comment: all in chorus... "What's ***wrong*** with the way I talk?"

Comment: I've heard of specific movies where an actor's voice is dubbed by another's, but never heard of an actor's voice *always* being dubbed, unless it's into another language.

Comment: Some specifics: Sam Jones's voice was dubbed in *Flash Gordon*, reportedly because he left immediately after production and they needed to loop some lines. Instead of trying to find someone that sounds like Jones, they elected to dub all of his dialogue. In *Greystoke: The Legend of Tarzan, Lord of the Apes*, Andie MacDowell's voice was dubbed by none other than Glenn Close, apparently because of MacDowell's southern accent.

Comment: Darth Vader was played by David Prowse but voiced by James Earl Jones. Given the prevalence of voice dubbing in cartoons and CG and through puppets I imagine this isn't a terribly uncommon thing to happen.

Comment: ALL of Aunt Beru's dialog was performed by another actress in ANH. Poor recording though.

Comment: **ALL** of these examples are bad. None of them describe an actor who is **always** (or even usually) dubbed... they're all describing actors who had their voices dubbed in a single film or film series, which happens all the time...

Comment: @Catija you are right, however, the question wasn't clear that it was looking for examples of actors whose voices are always replaced. An honest mistake.